# Height of rows to fill column - Bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this may be easy for most of you but I'm stuck with this issue.

I need to implement this design:
[Layout Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95CSF.png)

... and for now I've got this [Current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR7s6.png).The general structure is a row with col-3 and col-9, this col-9 has two rows, one for name and job title, and the other one for statistics in the page (col-3 for each of them). I need them to fill the height of his parent, but height property doesn't work. Which could be a clean solution? Thanks a lot.

Here is the structure, it's pretty simple tho.

```
<div class="row profile-header">
 <div class="col-md-3 user-image text-center">
   <img ...>
   <span>..</span>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="text-white">...</h2>
      <h4 class="text-muted">...</h4>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 stat">
      <h3>...</h3>
      <small>...</small>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either CSS Tables or Flexbox would be my recommendation.

Comment: Flexbox doesn't work well with Bootstrap3 responsive. Maybe tables could be the solution, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it does in this situation with very little fixing. See answer below....*I had some time* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on the parent and then `position:absolute; bottom: 0;` on the children.

[Nice explanation there.](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Comment: I could achieve what I wanted with this plus `width: 100%`, but it doesn't work well in `xs` and `sm` Bootstrap classes, so I only left these styles for `md` type. Any clearer solution will be welcome. Thanks for the explanation link!

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox** would be my recommendation although CSS tables might be an option too.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RaewrL)

Snippet Demo (view Fullscreen)

```css
.user-image {
  background: pink;
}
.user-image img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.profile-header {
  display: flex;
}
.right {
  background: #c0ffee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.stats {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.stat {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row profile-header">
  <div class="col-md-3 user-image text-center">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt="" />
    <span>User Ranking</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 right">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="text-white">User Name</h2>
        <h4 class="text-muted">reference</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center stats">
      <div class="col-md-3 stat">
        <h3>Some Stat</h3>
        <small>Some Stat</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 stat">
        <h3>Some Stat</h3>
        <small>Some Stat</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 stat">
        <h3>Some Stat</h3>
        <small>Some Stat</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 stat">
        <h3>Some Stat</h3>
        <small>Some Stat</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: With responsive I meant col-xs-like column classes, but I can fix that with media queries. Thanks!